# Dictionary to XML using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dictionary

So I have the function below that takes in a Dictionary and stores it into a XML file.

```
static void DictionaryToXML(Dictionary<string,User> UserClassDict, string xmldoc)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Moving User Dictionary data to XML (" + xmldoc + ")...");

            XElement el = new XElement("UserClassDictionary",
       UserClassDict.Select(kv => new XElement(kv.Key,
                    kv.Value.ControlNumber.Select(num => new XElement("ControlNumber", num)))));

            var xml = el.ToString();
            File.WriteAllText(xmldoc, xml);
        }
```

The output looks like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
        -<UserClassDictionary>-
<amsmith>
     <ControlNumber>1298136</ControlNumber>
</amsmith>
-<asnyder>
     <ControlNumber>1296234</ControlNumber>
</asnyder>
-<atreckey>
     <ControlNumber>1295885</ControlNumber>
</atreckey>

         </UserClassDictionary>
```

I need help in reformatting this XML. I would like the format to come out looking very similar to this:

```
<UserClassDictionary>
  <User id="amsmith">
        <ControlNumbers>
            <ControlNumber> 111222 </ControlNumber>
        </ControlNumbers>
  </User>
  <User id="asnyder">
        <ControlNumbers>
            <ControlNumber> 222333 </ControlNumber>
            <ControlNumber> 222444 </ControlNumber>
        </ControlNumbers>
  </User>
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, are you viewing the file in a browser like IE or the XMLViewer in Visual Studio? Try opening it in notepad (or the Text Viewer in Visual Studio)
.

Comment: @Tim The first block of XML that I posted was being viewed in IE.

Comment: I thought so.  If you open the file you create in Notepad, I bet it will look just fine.   IE lets you expand and collapse elements that have children (things like `-<atreckey>` in your posted code are what led me to ask the question).

Comment: @MaylorTaylor a little advice - in C# we use *camelCase* format for method parameter names. And its better to name control numbers property `ControlNumbers` thus it is a collection, not single number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will generate xml in format you want:

```
new XElement("UserClassDictionary",
      from kvp in UserClassDict
      select new XElement("User",
          new XAttribute("id", kvp.Key),
          new XElement("ControlNumbers",
               from cn in kvp.Value.ControlNumber
               select new XElement("ControlNumber", cn)
          )
      );
```

Comment: Yep - I didn't glance closely enough at the differences (I was thinking it was a display issue not a content issue). +1

Comment: @Tim no problem :) I think it should generate desired xml